# How do I make my program that creates RSA keys and encrypts and decrypts a file more secure

Tags: c++, security, linux, cryptography

```
#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cryptopp/queue.h>
#include <cryptopp/secblockfwd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cryptopp/integer.h>
#include <cryptopp/rsa.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
#include <cryptopp/files.h>
#include <cryptopp/secblock.h>
#include <sstream>


void SaveKey(const std::string filename, const CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey& key);
void SaveKey(const std::string filename, const CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey& key);
void Save(const std::string filename, const CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation& bt);
std::string Convert(CryptoPP::SecByteBlock block);
std::string decrypt(CryptoPP::SecByteBlock ciphertext, CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey priv_key);
CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey createPrivateKey(int size);
CryptoPP::SecByteBlock Encrypt(CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pub_key, const std::string file);
std::string read(std::string filename);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::string file = read(argv[1]);
    std::cout << file << "\n";
    //creates a public and private key
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey priv_key;
    priv_key.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 3072);
   
    
    CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pub_key(priv_key);
    SaveKey("priv", priv_key);
    SaveKey("pub", pub_key);

    //Encrypts the file using the public key
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock ciphertext = Encrypt(pub_key, file); 
    //Converts the encrypted data to string format and saves it in a file
    std::string encryptStr = Convert(ciphertext);

    std::ofstream encFile("encrypt.txt");
    encFile << encryptStr;
    
    std::cout << "Decrypted text "<< decrypt(ciphertext, priv_key) << "\n";
    return 0;
}



std::string decrypt(CryptoPP::SecByteBlock ciphertext, CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey priv_key){
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
    CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor decryptor(priv_key);

    //checks
    assert(0 != decryptor.FixedMaxPlaintextLength());
    assert(ciphertext.size() <= decryptor.FixedCiphertextLength());

   // Create recovered text space
    size_t dpl = decryptor.MaxPlaintextLength( ciphertext.size() );
    assert( 0 != dpl );
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock recovered( dpl );

    // Decoding text
    CryptoPP::DecodingResult result = decryptor.Decrypt( rnd,
    ciphertext, ciphertext.size(), recovered );

    // More sanity checks
    assert( result.isValidCoding );        
    assert( result.messageLength <= decryptor.MaxPlaintextLength( ciphertext.size() ) );
   //Resised the buffer to the correct length and converts it to string format
    recovered.resize(result.messageLength);
    std::string message = Convert(recovered);
    return message;
}
void Save(const std::string filename, const CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation& bt){
    CryptoPP::FileSink file(filename.c_str());
    bt.CopyTo(file);
    file.MessageEnd();

}
void SaveKey(const std::string filename, const CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey& key){
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue queue;
    key.Save(queue);
    Save(filename, queue);

}
void SaveKey(const std::string filename, const CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey& key){
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue queue;
    key.Save(queue);
    Save(filename, queue);
}

CryptoPP::SecByteBlock Encrypt(CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pub_key, const std::string file){
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;

    CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor encryptor(pub_key);
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock plaintext(reinterpret_cast<const CryptoPP::byte*>(&file[-1]), file.size());


    size_t ecl = encryptor.CiphertextLength(plaintext.size());
    assert(ecl != -1);
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock ciphertext(ecl);
    encryptor.Encrypt(rnd, plaintext, plaintext.size(), ciphertext);
    return ciphertext;
}
std::string Convert(CryptoPP::SecByteBlock block){
      std::string str;
      str.resize(block.size());
      memcpy(&str[0], &block[0], str.size());
      return str;
}
std::string read(std::string filename){
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    assert(file.is_open());
    std::ostringstream sstr;
    sstr << file.rdbuf();
    return sstr.str();


}
```

This code starts by reading in an external file passed in through arg[0]. Them it creates an saves an RSA public and private key using crypto++. Then it encrypts the file using the public key and saves it to a file. Then it decrypts it and prints the result. Is there a way that I can make it more secure, more readable and more efficient.

Comment: My standard comment on encryption. Don't roll your own (if you are doing this for practical use). Assuming this is for learning purposes, fine.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I don't like is the need to load the whole file into memory before you start encryption. This will only work for relatively small files.

I would expect the interface to be more like:

```
 std::ifstream   file(file);
 std::ofstream   encryptedFile(file + ".encryp");
 EnctptedStream  encryptedStream(encryptedFile, publicKey);

 encryptedStream << file.rdbuf();
```

So:

```
 // Make the encryption be a normal stream like object.
 // Then you can send data to the encryption stream just like
 // you send data to a normal stream (so it can be used anywhere
 // you would normally use a stream the using code does not need
 // to know that this is a special stream).
 //
 // I would also make it a wrapper of a stream so we can send the
 // data to any other normla stream be that a file or a memory
 // buffer.
 class EnctptedStream: public std::ostream
 {
      public:
           EnctptedStream(std::ostream& stream, Key key);
 };
```